# Book recommendation on statistical computing?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

Topics on importance sampling, Monte Carlo, MCMC etc.

Comment: Please try a little harder to make this precise. Are you looking for a book that tells you how to use software or one that tells you how to write original programs? What background in computing/statistics/mathematics are you expecting to be assumed? Any language or package or environment or specific software assumed? etc.

Comment: You should edit your question to be more precise. Are you interested in books on Monte Carlo methods in statistical computing (as I assumed)? If so edit your question and its title to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a "must read" position and also very readable:

- Robert, C. & Casella, G. (2004). *Monte Carlo Statistical Methods.* Springer.

This two introduce the topic with examples of code in R what I personally found very helpful:

- Robert, C. & Casella, G. (2009). *Introducing Monte Carlo
  Methods with R.* Springer.
- Suess, E.A. & Trumbo, B.E. (2010).
  *Introduction to Probability Simulation and Gibbs Sampling with R.* Springer.